# Qt: How to make the window below the virtual joy pad receive mouse/touch event?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have implemented a Qt based desktop GUI. It has a main GUI window (written in traditional QWidget) and a QtQuick window for a virtual joypad on top of the main window. It can be seen as follow:
[image]

The virtual joypad window blocks a large part of the main window.
I could make the pink window's **background transparent** but it **still blocks the touch/mouse event**.

How can I make the **center part** of pink window **'disappear'** so the user can **still control large parts of the main GUI**?

Comment: Using widgets, you can implement mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* e) and ignore the event (e->ignore()), than the event will be propagated to the parent widget. I've not tried with quick windows, but I think it's the same.

Comment: But my pink window is a top level window?

Comment: Maybe you can use QQuickWidget for your pink window and make it child of the main window

Comment: In that case, according to Qt's document, I cannot make it transparent in color.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the controller translucent and frame less. On windows platform it will allow you to create fully transparent solution that can be interacted with. It will not work on Linux aka i did not try to make it work. I'm using qt 5.8. 
Also you can try setting up stylesheet for your controller as background:rgba(0,0,0,0).